# Returning pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

So I am new to C and I have a question that I am hoping someone can help me with. Suppose I have a string.

```
typedef struct String {
    char *value;
    int size;
} String;
```

And what I want to do is initialize this string with a function. My first question is which would be better

```
bool init_String(String **s, char *p) {
    if (s == NULL || *s == NULL) {
        return false;
    }
    (*s)->value = p;
    (*s)->size = strlen(p);
    return true;
}
```

In this version the function takes a pointer to a pointer and doesn't return the string. My other version is this one:

```
String *init_String(String **s, char *p) {
    if (s == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    s->value = p;
    s->size = strlen(p);
    return s;
}
```

Which is better for the user? My second question is is it better to malloc according to the user or according to me. In other words should the user malloc a String and then pass it to the init function or should the init function work as alloc_init and do both the call to malloc and the string initialization?

Thanks

Comment: Just as you call your `struct` "String" does not make it one. And the second function is wrong.

Comment: if the second doesn't toss up at least a warning about incompatible pointer types, you need to turn up your warning levels. Or, that isn't the **real** code and you actually have `String *s` for the parameter. Finally, "better" isn't really applicable here, since that simple difference (`String **` vs. `String*`) indicates a fundamental difference in *purpose*. The latter (`String*`) would usually be used to initialize an *existing* structure; the former (`String **`) would be used to initialize a *pointer*, usually with its own dynamic allocation.

Comment: If the point of function `init_string()` is to initialize a `struct String` that was allocated elsewhere, then there is no point in passing a pointer to a pointer to that struct.  If you pass a pointer directly to the struct (i.e. a `String *` rather than a `String **`) then the function can update that struct's members, and those updates will be visible to the caller.

Comment: @Olaf what are you even saying??

Comment: Drop the Typedef and you will understand better the Language. Later do what you think is OK for you

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
typedef struct String {
  char *value;
  size_t size;
  int ref; // if nonzero, do not free(value)
} String;

String refer_String(const char *p) {
  String out = { p, strlen(p), 1 };
  return out;
}

String copy_String(const char *p) {
  String out = { strdup(p), strlen(p), 0 };
  return out;
}

void free_String(const String *s) {
  if (!s->ref) {
    free(s->value);
  }
}
```

This provides a way to refer to existing literal strings like your original code, but also a way to create new strings which may be modified.

Comment: Although they may sometimes be expedient -- and I've used them -- I find "I own this" flags such as your `String.ref` to be pretty smelly.  I'd rather it be invariant whether the data pointed to by a given type belong to that type or not.

Comment: What is the point of `ref`? Why not just initialize `value` to `NULL`, there is nothing wrong with `free(NULL);`

Comment: This will become a problem when using/modifying the contents. Also passing the `struct`s is problematic, as they require a lot of copying and cause problems if passed by pointers. That makes the handle very uncomfortable and you always have to keep internal semantics in mind.